# railstutorial where is debug information coming from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

In chapter 7 I'm getting the following output with

```
--- !ruby/hash-with-ivars:ActionController::Parameters
elements:
  controller: static_pages
  action: home
ivars:
  :@permitted: false
```

could someone explain where the hash-with-ivars is coming from and what  ivars:
      :@permitted: false means?

Comment: Is @permitted any of your instance variable in static_pages#home?

Comment: No @permitted is not in the controller or in the html.  I've checked every file I created and can't find it.

Comment: @DCR was there a fix for this?  I'm thinking of trying doing the indifferent access to the params as I'm out of ideas & none of 30+ of these SO's answer my question

Comment: read the checked answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Interesting question! I searched all library sources of a rails project for `'hash-with-ivars'` and only a single place came up: the [`psych` ruby library](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych) for (de-)serializing arbitrary objects to and from [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). Specifically, these are  links to the source code for [reading](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb#L265) and [writing](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#L481) this YAML structure.

In [Chapter 7](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#fig-home_page_with_debug) of the Rails Tutorial, this output comes out as the output of the `debug(params)` command that you are instructed to put in a template. The `debug` command apparently calls the `psych` library to show a readable representation of the object (`params` in this case).

Now, `params` - the universal Rails data structure to hold parameters passed from URLs or forms - is an object that behaves like a `Hash` but is not pure hash: it is **an instance of class `ActionController::Parameters`** which is a **subclass of `Hash`**, let's see the [class definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L44):

```
module ActionController
  # ...
  class Parameters < ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    # ...
  end
end
```

while `HashWithIndifferentAccess` is a direct subclass of `Hash`.

As a subclass of `Hash`, the `params` object can hold other data besides the hash itself and this is what `psych` actually supports when trying to print the object in a readable form. Besides printing all the hash elements (under the `elements` key), it tries to also list **all instance variables** of the object and prints it under the `ivars` key.

So, all in all, this debug print simply says that the object debugged is an instance of the `ActionController::Parameters` class, which is a subclass of `Hash`, that besides it's hash elements has also a `@permitted` instance variable defined and it is currently set to `false`. The two elements, by the way, the `controller` and `action` are parameters used internally by Rails for routing.

When you look into the source of the class again, you will indeed find the `@permitted` variable right in the constructor:

```
class Parameters < ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  # ...
  def initialize(attributes = nil)
    super(attributes)
    @permitted = self.class.permit_all_parameters
  end
end
```

Finally, from the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permitted-3F) we can conclude that the `@permitted` variable holds the state of the params permission. I.e. it is set to `true` after the params are permitted by using the `permit` method:

```
permitted = params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
permitted.permitted? # this prints out the @permitted instance variable
# => true
```

**Update: why the RailsTutorial's debug output differs**

The debug output at the RailsTutorial differs a bit - it does not print `ivar`s. Why? It is because the feature for serializing `hash-with-ivars` was added to the `psych` gem in its [version 2.0.9](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/commit/8f84ad0fc711a82a1040def861cb121e8985fd4c). The `psych` gem is now a part of the Ruby standard library and this particular version of it **has been [added](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/136b07aec8118dabb3b394d1e8b1a4c24d022b4a) to the stdlib 2.3.0 preview1 version**.

So, the mysteriously different output has a simple explanation: the RailsTutorial author most probably used ruby 2.2 or earlier when writing the book and this ruby version did not display instance variables in the `Hash` debug output yet. Actually, there are hints in the tutorial that [suggest](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#sec-ruby_version_number) that the author used ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: this is a great answer but why doesn't the example output from the tutorial match?  I spoke to the author and he can't explain what's going on.

Comment: I need to wait 8 hours before sending you the bounty.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is straight teamwork and exactly why the community S.O. is vital to the coding world.