# Can "!ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters" be removed when object.to_yaml (YAML) in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, yaml

I am using Ruby 2.3.0 & rails 4.2.6. I have a hash with nested array of hashes in params, and when I write it into a file

```
hash = {"abc"=> [{"abc1"=>[{"key1" => value1},{"key2" => value2}]}]}

File.open("abc.yaml",'w+') {|f| f.write hash.to_yaml(:indentation => 8) }
```

abc.yaml

```
 ---
 abc:
 - !ruby/hash-with-ivars:ActionController::Parameters
    elements:
            abc1: &2
            - !ruby/hash-with-ivars:ActionController::Parameters
                    elements:
                            key1: value1
                            key2: value2
                    ivars:
                            :@permitted: false
            - !ruby/hash-with-ivars:ActionController::Parameters
                    elements:
                            key1: value1
                            key2: value2
                    ivars:
                            :@permitted: false
    ivars:
            :@permitted: false
            :@converted_arrays: !ruby/object:Set
                    hash:
                            *2: true
```

Its mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655635/railstutorial-where-is-debug-information-coming-from)
It is because the feature for serializing hash-with-ivars was added to the psych gem in its version 2.0.9. The psych gem is now a part of the Ruby standard library and this particular version of it has been added to the stdlib 2.3.0 preview1 version.

But I am trying to keep the yaml file clean by not adding any other extra params. How can I remove !ruby/hash-with-ivars: ActionController::Parameters , elements and ivars while writing into a file?

Comment: how does `hash` look like?

Comment: You have to provide Rails version and type of "hash" at least. It seems its `4.x` and `ActionController::Parameters` respectively. So to get plain yaml you should get plain Hash first! Use something like `hash.to_hash.to_yaml` or `hash.as_json.to_yaml`

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk to_hash worked! Thanks! Can you please add it as an answer?

Comment: @dips Ok, added, thank you too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually your `hash` is instance of `ActionController::Parameters` and not `Hash` class. So `#to_yaml` stores `ActionController::Parameters` inner representation also.
To get plain YAML you have to convert it to `Hash` first.

**Rails 4**:

```
hash.to_hash.to_yaml(indentation: 8)
```

**Rails 5** - `#to_hash` is deprecated, use `#to_unsafe_h` (returns `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`) or `#as_json` instead:

```
hash.to_unsafe_h.to_yaml(indentation: 8)
```

Comment: Thank you for the details :)